# How to use the Visual Studio Code to navigate Linux kernel source

Tags: visual-studio-code, preprocessor

I am converting from Eclipse CDT. The preprocessor macro feature is a must when navigating through C/C++ code with preprocessor defines (whether explicitly specified in Makefile or included through an external auto-generated header file). Without this, navigating the Linux source would be impossible, as described on [this seminal wiki page on using Eclipse to study the Linux code](https://wiki.eclipse.org/HowTo_use_the_CDT_to_navigate_Linux_kernel_source). I am looking for an equivalent feature for Visual Studio Code. Would appreciate a pointer.

Answer (score 9):

1. Install ms-vscode.cpptools extension.
2. Open kernel source folder in VSCode.
3. Follow the [instructions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/Getting%20started%20with%20IntelliSense%20configuration.md), add "${workspaceFolder}/include" and "${workspaceFolder}/arch/{your arch}/include" to includePath, "your arch" is x86/arm etc.
4. Wait for IntelliSence indexing.

Comment: I'm working with kernel and this answer worked like a charm. I notice that if you are working with modules development you can also use your machine's linux headers.
In my case, added to `settings.json` :  ` C_Cpp.default.includePath": ["/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-custom-buster/arch/x86/include/" , "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-custom-buster/include/"] `

Answer (score 7):

As of today I have found the use of the [vscode-linux-kernel](https://github.com/amezin/vscode-linux-kernel) project to be superior to both answers listed above, as navigation through the code and Intellisense works very well.

The project is released to the public domain.

Comment: This might be the best solution here.

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked best for me (fixing some issue of the snippet in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53843634)):

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/arch/<arch>/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/arch/<arch>/include/generated"
            ],
            "forcedInclude": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/BUILD/include/generated/autoconf.h"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "__KERNEL__"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gg", # replace this with your compiler (also gcc cross-compiler)
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Where you may replace `<arch>` with your actual architecture.

Answer (score 3):

I did't need to add the arch folder (for x86_64 it was actually empty), but add some basic defines to make compiler specific types and macros visible to intellisense. My minimal config is shown below. For perfect results you would have to add all defines as configured in your kernel .config file (e.g. CONFIG_MMU). There are many of those, so typically you will only focus on the few you really care about.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "__GNUC__",
                "__KERNEL__"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: _you would have to add all defines as configured in your kernel .config file_  All defines are already in `include/generated/autoconf.h` (under `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/`), should be enough to `forceInclude` it in `c_cpp_properties.json`.

Answer (score 1):

[Makefile Tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.makefile-tools) provides IntelliSense configurations to the VS Code C/C++ Extension for Makefile projects. We dont have to manage the `c_cpp_properties.json` manually.

It's the best solution I'm aware of to work with the Linux kernel code in VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, none of the above answers really solved the problem. Here is my solution.

1. Disable or uninstall the official `C/C++ plugin`.
2. Install the `clangd` plugin.
3. Build the kernel with `clang`:

```
/path/to/kernel_source$ make CC=clang defconfig
/path/to/kernel_source$ make CC=clang -j16
```

4. Generate the `compile_commands.json`:

```
/path/to/kernel_source$ python ./scripts/clang-tools/gen_compile_commands.py
```

If no error occures, you will find `compile_commands.json` in `/path/to/kernel_source/`.

5. Configure the `clangd` plugin with the following parameters:

[image: image.png]

6. Open any `C` file in kernel source and enjoy it :)

[image: image.png]

Comment: clang really support kernel building?

Comment: @andreykyz Yes. https://docs.kernel.org/kbuild/llvm.html

Answer (score 0):

These responses are helpful, but https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/programming-language.html would indicate that `cStandard` should be `gnu11` (according to comment by @pqnet).

Comment: same document now point to `gnu11` instead